# Android Download Base64 Encoded data, decode it and save it to file

Tags: java, android, base64

I need to download Base64 Encoded data from Server using HttpUrlConnection. And then decode it and save it to the file.

I have completed task making connection and all. I can get Data in Base64 string fromat from HTTP response body, but need some pointers moving from here. How to decode it and then save it the file.

Is Base64InputStrem a good idea ? then How do I wrap it in File Strem ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) to decode Base64. Saving it to file is more [tricky](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), you need to know where to put it.